# C++ class declarations (inheritence)

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Define classes X, Y, and Z, such that Y is a child of X and Z is a child of Y.  Class Y should be abstract.

How will be the declaration for Class Y as it should be abstract?

Comment: It needs to have at least one pure virtual member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class X
{
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
    // For defining an abstract class without pure virtual functions:
    virtual ~Y() = 0;

    virtual void method() = 0;  
};

class Z : public Y
{
public:
    void method() override
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Close, but missing some punctuation and making up a keyword.

Comment: Looks like some other language than C++ to me.

Comment: Closer, but there's no `abstract` keyword in C++. A class is implicitly abstract if it has a pure virtual member function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Are you sure? if i declare a class with abstract keyword without any pure virtual function, i can't create an object from that and i get this error: class "" was declared with the class modifier 'abstract'

Comment: @MohammadRB: I'm completely sure that `abstract` is not a C++ keyword. Either you're not compiling C++, or you have a compiler with a non-standard extension.

Comment: @MohammadRB: [This extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b0z6b513.aspx), perhaps.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks, i don't know that abstract isn't part of standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Y {
  public:
    virtual void foobar() = 0;
};
```

This is an abstract class in the c++ sense.